# Laravel query builder add complex query result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have three models with the following hierarchy :

- User

  - id
  - ....some other properties
- Journey

  - id
  - user_id
  - budget
  - ....some other properties
- Confirmation

  - id
  - journey_id
  - user_id
  - ....some other properties

I have a `HasMany` from `User` to `Journey`, a `HasMany` from `Journey` to `Confirmation`.

I want to get the sum for a column of the `journeys` table by going through the `confirmations` table but I cannot create an intermediate `HasManyThrough` relation between `User` and `Journey` by using `Confirmation`.

I have tried to do

```php
public function journeysMade(): HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Journey::class, Confirmation::class);
}

// And after,
User::with(...)->withSum('journeysMade','budget')
```

But it was not possible because the relations are not adapted.

With hindsight, the sql query I want to translate would look like

```sql
select coalesce(sum(journeys.budget), 0) as income
from journeys
    inner join confirmations c on journeys.id = c.journey_id
where c.user_id = ? and c.status = 'finalized';
```

How can I implement this query considering how I will use my query builder :

```php
$driversQueryBuilder = User::with(['profile', 'addresses']); // Here
$pageSize = $request->input('pageSize', self::DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE);
$pageNumber = $request->input('pageNumber', self::DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER);
$driversPaginator = (new UserFilterService($driversQueryBuilder))
        ->withStatus(Profile::STATUS_DRIVER)
        ->withCountry($request->input('country'))
        ->withSex($request->input('sex'))
        ->withActive($request->has('active') ? $request->boolean('active') : null)
        ->get()
        ->paginate(perPage: $pageSize, page: $pageNumber);
return response()->json(['data' => $driversPaginator]);
```

The reason why I want to get a builder is because `UserFilterService` expects a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

Do you have any idea about how I can solve this problem ?

Comment: Why does your `Confirmation` model have both `journey_id` and `user_id`? Is it possible that a confirmation is associated with a user that is different to the user noted in the `Journey`?

Comment: Yes. The journeys are published by a User and Confirmed by a different User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what exactly you want to sum, but I think you need the following query

```
$user->whereHas('journeys', function($query) {
  $query->whereHas('confirmations', function($subQuery) {
    $subQuery->sum('budget);
  }
});
```

If you the above query isn't summing the budget you need, you just add another layer of abstraction with whereHas methods to get exactly what you need. Hope this helps!

EDIT:

```
$user->whereHas('confirmations', function($q) {
  $q->withSum('journeys', 'budget')->journeys_sum_budget;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explained correctly this part.
I cannot use the relation between user and journey because they don't express the same things. I want to retrieve the sum of the budgets of the journeys the user has confirmed, not the sum of the budgets of the journeys the user has published

Comment: Do you have a user_id in confirmations?

Comment: Yes, I have indicated it in the hierarchy